# Interact with virtual serial device in polling mode in linux C

Tags: linux-kernel, serial-port, linux-device-driver, android-kernel

I'm trying to enable polling support for a serial over USB driver on an android kernel, so that I can debug it using kgdboc. I based myself on the code from these githubs:

- https://github.com/dankex/kgdb-android
- https://github.com/jacktang310/KernelDebugOnNexus6P

However, I can't find a way to enable and use char by char polling mode via a C program on userland. Which makes debugging very difficult, since the only thing I can do is to set kgdboc to `/dev/ttyGS0` and then send "g" to sysrq-trigger, and pray it works.

In other terms, I need a userland program that triggers the code path which reaches the following operations on the `tty_operations` structure:

```
.poll_init = gs_poll_init,
.poll_get_char = gs_poll_get_char,
.poll_put_char = gs_poll_put_char,
```

Instead, whenever I write to `/dev/ttyGS0` I trigger the "write" operation.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Those aren't supposed to be used by userspace, but rather exist for KGDB to communicate with the *remote* debug host.  What are you actually trying to do here, *fake* traffic from a debug host?

Comment: The end of https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kgdb/EnableKGDB.html suggests the idea that you could just put a breakpoint in a rarely used kernel code path and cause that to execute... though I'm not sure I'd agree with their choice of what to trap.

Comment: I'm trying to modify a serial over USB driver to allow polling mode, so that I can debug the kernel of the device.

Comment: Then why are you asking how to trigger these from userspace?  Only the KDGB target side code should be using them, and the other end is the computer on the other end of the wire.   Also realize that serial-over-USB is very complex involving moving parts many places in the kernel, it's not necessarily a given that KGDB can handle that (though it would obviously be useful, so maybe they have found a way to do so).

Comment: Further /dev/ttyGS0 should be a built in UART so it's unclear why you are pursuing USB serial on the *target* side at all.  USB serial on the *debug host* side shouldn't at first glance seem be a major issue as that side would just use normal userspace serial APIs - granted, there are some latency issues but that's so overwhelmingly the serial solution on popular developer machines that it is likely those were long ago taken into account.

Comment: I'm asking how to trigger these from userspace because it's much more convenient for debugging purposes than having to compile the kernel, reboot, try, oops, reboot, etc.

Comment: I realize that KGDB is very complex, but it's been done with a different version of the DWC3 driver so I know it's possible. In order for KGDB to work, it needs to have polling mode enabled and have the polling functions compiled into the kernel module. I'm modifying the debug target, as it's the one that's missing the polling support (I guess it doesn't matter for the debug host). /dev/ttyGS0 is the built-in serial over USB port for this device. (What's UART?) Thanks for the responses!

Comment: Since those are not designed to be used by userspace you would need to hack up your own test interface.  Look up how to write a simple driver that exports a sysfs node or something like that, and connect it through to test logic.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Thanks a lot for the insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a driver that exports a sysfs node as Chris Stratton suggested.

I based myself on [this tutorial](http://pradheepshrinivasan.github.io/2015/07/02/Creating-an-simple-sysfs/)